# Consultar registro dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Estoy listando los registros desde MySQL, ahi consulto tres tablas, usuarios, registros, cursos, la tabla que muestro actualmente es con los registros de los usuarios, pero con el id del usuario debo consultar en la tabla registros  por el id del usuario el curso que este posee asociado, ahi dentro de la respuesta a la consulta de la tabla registros hago un console mostrado el CodUsuario, mi idea es como comparar esos registros con la tabla usuarios y asi saber si existe o no el id del usuario en esa tabla, si existe sacar el curso que posee activo.

O lo otro que pienso es que podria hacer una nueva consulta a la tabla registros con el id dentro de la consulta a la tabla usuarios, pero no se como hacerlo

```
seintAdmin.controller('adminUsuarios', ['i18nService', 'cargaDatos', '$scope', '$uibModal', function(i18nService, cargaDatos, $scope, $uibModal){
i18nService.setCurrentLang('es');
var salida = this;
var usu = {};
var cur = {};
var reg = {};
salida.datosTabla = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableFiltering: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 24,
    rowHeight: 24,
    showGridFooter:true,
    paginationPageSizes: [100, 200, 500, 1000, 10000],
    paginationPageSize: 100,
    gridMenuShowHideColumns: false,

    columnDefs: [
            {name: 'id', visible: false},
            {name: 'Nombre', displayName: 'Nombre', enableColumnMenu: false},
            {name: 'Cedula', displayName: 'Cédula', enableColumnMenu: false},
            {name: 'Empresa', displayName: 'Empresa', enableColumnMenu: false},
            {name: 'FechaReg', visible: false},
            {name: 'Curso:', displayName: 'Curso:', enableColumnMenu: false}

    ]
};
cargaTabla();
function cargaTabla() {
    cargaDatos.leer('usuarios').then(function(respUsu){            
        cargaDatos.leer('registros').then(function(respReg){
            cargaDatos.leer('cursos').then(function(respCur){
                var resp = [];
                salida.cursos = respCur;

                angular.forEach(respCur, function(valor, llave){
                    cur[valor.id] = valor.NombreCurso;

                });                  

                angular.forEach(respUsu, function(valor, llave){

                     resp.push({
                         'id': valor.id,
                         'Nombre': valor.Nombre,
                         'Cedula': valor.Cedula,
                         'Empresa': valor.Empresa,
                         'FechaReg': valor.FechaReg,
                         'Curso:': valor.id 
                     });
                });

                angular.forEach(respReg, function(valor, llave){
                   reg[valor.id] = valor.CodUsuario;
                   console.log(reg[valor.CodUsuario]);
                    });

                salida.datosTabla.data = resp;
                });
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: creo que en este caso seria mas facil que hicieras una consulta especifica con INNER JOIN entre las tres tablas y sus ids relacionales, para obtener una tabla resultado con los datos que necesitas